# Can I get feedback on assignment? (chromatography)

Tags: chromatography

HW question asks me why samples can be separated into their components by chromatography. My answer is that each component in the mixture will have different affinity for the solvent (mobile) phase as it moves up the paper, because each component can be more or less polar/nonpolar. The technique exploits the fact that polar components will move further distance with a polar solvent, while less polar components move less distance. Is this basically correct? Thanks

Comment: You missed an important interaction.

Comment: also an interaction with the water on the paper (polarity again?) is that what you mean?

Comment: Not just the water, but the components in the mixture with the paper. If the components have zero affinity for the paper, they would move with the solvent front (even if they have very low affinity for the solvent).

Answer (score 0):

You really missed something about chromatography and you assume that the stationery phase is neutral.

In fact, chromatography is based on the balance between the interactions between a component and BOTH the mobile phase (aka the eluent) and the stationary phase. Depending on your choice of mobile and stationery phases, results can be entirely different.